# C++ A multiple inheritance pproblem with pure virtual functions

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have produced a minimal example to replicate the problem I am seeing with a more complex class hierarchy structure:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


class A
{
protected:

    virtual
    ~A() = 0;

};

inline
A::~A() {}

class B : public A
{
public:

    virtual
    ~B()
    {
    }

    std::string B_str;
};

class BB : public A
{
public:

    virtual
    ~BB()
    {
    }

    std::string BB_str;
};

class C : public A
{
protected:

    virtual
    ~C()
    {
    }

    virtual
    void Print() const = 0;
};

class D : public B, public BB, public C
{
public:

    virtual
    ~D()
    {
    }
};

class E : public C
{
public:

    void Print() const
    {
        std::cout << "E" << std::endl;
    }
};

class F : public E, public D
{
public:

    void Print_Different() const
    {
        std::cout << "Different to E" << std::endl;
    }

};


int main()
{

    F f_inst;

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling with `g++ --std=c++11 main.cpp` produces the error:

```
error: cannot declare variable ‘f_inst’ to be of abstract type ‘F’

    F f_inst;

note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘F’:

    class F : public E, public D
          ^
note:   virtual void C::Print() const

    void Print() const = 0;
         ^
```

So the compiler thinks that `Print()` is pure virtual.

But, I have specified what `Print()` should be in `class E`.

So, I've misunderstood some of the rules of inheritance.

What is my misunderstanding, and how can I correct this problem?

Note: It will compile if I remove the inheritance `: public D` from `class F`.

Comment: `F` is also derived from `D`, and `D` is derived from `C`, and the `C::Print` in that instance of `C` has not been overridden.

Comment: One option is to use virtual inheritance, which would mean that `F` only has one `C` ancestor, and the `D` and `E` share the `C` base. A search term is "diamond inheritance problem"

Comment: @M.M `class D` is to be used as an abstract base class for a vector of base class pointers. I cannot implement the function `Print()` in `class D`. What should I do?

Comment: Another option is to override `Print` in `F` (and the implementation could be to call `E::Print();`)

Comment: I tried inheriting `class D` with `virtual` but that doesn't help...?

Comment: Overriding those members in `class F` will be a pretty ugly solution... Is there an alternative?

Comment: `D` and `E` need to inherit `C` virtually

Comment: not really; you currently have two `C::Print` functions in your object, the only options are to override both of them,  or change your object so that there is only one `C` base

Comment: @M.M Horray! That seems to have done the trick - add that as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Currently your `F` is derived from `C` in two different ways. This means that an `F` object has two separate `C` bases, and so there are two instances of `C::Print()`.

You only override the one coming via `E` currently.

To solve this you must take one of the following options:

- Also override the one coming via `D`, either by implementing `D::Print()` or `F::Print()`
- Make `Print` non-pure
- Use *virtual inheritance* so that there is only a single `C` base.

For the latter option, the syntax adjustments would be:

```
class E : virtual public C
```

and

```
class D : public B, public BB, virtual public C
```

This means that `D` and `E` will both have the same `C` instance as their parent, and so the override `E::Print()` overrides the function for all classes 'downstream' of that `C`.

For more information , look up "diamond inheritance problem".  See also [Multiple inheritance FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/multiple-inheritance)